# Spotify SDK get rid of authentication popup when already authenticated

Tags: android, spotify

I have started to develop an app with the spotify sdk. I have noticed that everytime you start the app a popup appears with a loading spinner for a split second.

I have implemented my authentication flow exactly the way it is described on the [spotify docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/).

Isn't there a way to hide this popup in any way?

Comment: You do not need to use the Spotify SDK for every time your app runs. Hold onto the token that you get back (e.g., in a file) and use it in future runs of your app. If you offer a logout mechanism, clear that token, so you know to re-authenticate in a future run if needed.

Comment: oh, okay. So its a different kind of token than the one you get through the web api. Because that one you need to refresh every now and then. But i will try this thanks.